# Can't get the authorization code of Quickbooks API through curl but it works through the url

Tags: php, api, curl, post, oauth

I just want to get the authorization code to obtain the access token to make API requests, I did the step manaully through the pasting the link in the browser and it works.
but through Curl PHP doesn't work I get empty string of size 1400 char.

this's the sample on Quickbooks API doc

```
curl -X POST    'https://appcenter.intuit.com/connect/oauth2?
     client_id=Q3ylJatCvnkYqVKLmkxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxkYB36b5mws7HkKUEv9aI&response_type=code&
        scope=com.intuit.quickbooks.accounting&
        redirect_uri=https://www.mydemoapp.com/oauth-redirect&
        state=security_token%3D138r5719ru3e1%26url%3Dhttps://www.mydemoapp.com/oauth-redirect'
```

[Quickbooks API Auth code ref](https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/develop/authentication-and-authorization/oauth-2.0)

I Turned to Curl PHP with replacing my credentials, when I visit the link I get the auth code and I could obtian the access token but can't do it in the back-end
**the dir of the page that I want to get the auth code in is https://roifelawgroup.com/clientform/login/info_submit.php

but the redirect link just : https://roifelawgroup.com/ with login creds is this could be the problem?**

**However I tried with the same page redirect link didn't work**

```
function authcode(){
            
$url = "https://appcenter.intuit.com/connect/oauth2?client_id=ABfQBA8VYPPUETO5isi2v8p39lQwEsw1ozL7NhZxxxxxx&response_type=code&scope=com.intuit.quickbooks.payment&redirect_uri=https://roifelawgroup.com&state=security_token%3D138r5719ru3e1%26url%3Dhttps://roifelawgroup.com";

$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); // if removed this line I get  301 permanently moved  

$headers = array(
   "Content-Length: 0",
);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
//for debug only!
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$resp = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
var_dump($resp);
 

}
```

Comment: This kind of OAuth authorization _requires_ user interaction. You need to redirect the user to the login URL in their browser, you can not just do it all in the background on the server side.

Comment: Sorry, May I ask which Login URL do you mean? but when I obtain the auth code in the Playground of Quickbooks API it doesn't require conformation or when using the PHP SDK. 

So what's the best alternative way to obtain the auth code then inserty it automatically in the function to obtain the access token to be able to use the API.

Comment: The one mentioned in step 9, https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/develop/authentication-and-authorization/oauth-2.0#redirect-to-server

Comment: https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/develop/authentication-and-authorization/faq#how-access-tokens-work: _Tokening starts when users connect to your app. Your app sends users an authorization request. This request redirects users to sign in to their QuickBooks Online company. We ask if they’re willing to give your app permission to access their data. This flow is called “user consent.”_

Comment: But when I insert the link of the API request for the auth code I get the result without signing in again which is this's url `$url = "https://appcenter.intuit.com/connect/oauth2?client_id=ABfQBA8VYPPUETO5isi2v8p39lQwEsw1ozL7NhZxxxxxx&response_type=code&scope=com.intuit.quickbooks.payment&redirect_uri=https://roifelawgroup.com&state=security_token%3D138r5719ru3e1%26url%3Dhttps://roifelawgroup.com";` 

I made the redirect link as the website that I use the script in, I remember having something similar with Google Ads API without also singing in again for the auth code.

Comment: Can I handle this part automatically through Oauth SDK of Quickbooks with having user interaction to sign in which is pretty normal in the API requests to automate the auth code and already I get the access token when I replace the auth code.

Comment: If you don't ask for any new permissions the user has not granted yet, then they are not supposed to be bothered with the permission screen again; in that case, you redirect them to the login dialog URL, and that redirects back to your app right away, without showing the user anything in between.

Comment: Yes it doesn't want new permissions because when I visit the link I get the auth code normally but when I try to get the the reponse through CUrl PHP, It doesn't work the big problem that the support of Quickbooks API developers are not repsponsive.

Comment: When I visit the url in the main question I get the reponse also the URL bar of the browser.